Can a neural network be used to find the best parameters of an algorithm?
I've developed a computer vision algorithm that produces a binary result from an image. This algorithm depends on a number of parameters.
Is it possible to use a neural network to learn the best parameters, given the outcome of the execution of the algorithm on several images?

are these parameters dependent on the image you are processing or they should be something generic?

Maybe, but it's likely overkill.  In hyperparameterization, random search, successive-halving or, lastly, evolutionary optimization is generally more than enough.  This is not to mention the dozen other methods people have proposed over the years.
